# Nginx not logging (restart needed)

Tags: linux, nginx

We're running Nginx on a couple Ubuntu servers (16.04) and all in all everything is working fine. However after some time (few days) Nginx stops logging requests to the logs (/var/log/nginx/[host].log). If I restart Nginx logging resumes/starts back up. But pretty frustrating as I don't know exactly when logging stops and all in all, don't want to not be logging the traffic.

Thoughts on what could be causing this or how to fix?

Logrotate config:

```
/var/log/nginx/*.log {
    daily
    missingok
    rotate 14
    compress
    delaycompress
    notifempty
    create 0640 www-data adm
    sharedscripts
    prerotate
        if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
            run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
        fi \
    endscript
    postrotate
        invoke-rc.d nginx rotate >/dev/null 2>&1
    endscript
}
```

Comment: How have you configured log rotation?

Comment: Updated the question with the logrotate config. This is the default config that was loaded when installing nginx (never looked at until now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran across this question just the other day:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/259091/nginx-log-rotation-doesnt-seem-to-be-working-correctly

Looking at that answer, on our servers I changed the line:

```
invoke-rc.d nginx rotate
```

to:

```
invoke-rc.d nginx reload
```

instead and now things appear to be working as expected now. Not sure why the default logrorate config for these Ubuntu and Debian boxes aren't doing that already but `rotate` does not seem to be working as maybe it was intended?